Supporting logout+jwt for back-channel logout with spring-webflux
I'm trying to implement OIDC back-channel logout on a spring webflux application (spring-cloud-gateway).
I configured my http security as followed:
.oidcLogout(oidcLogout -> oidcLogout
    .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository)
    .backChannel(Customizer.withDefaults()))

The back-channel logout request is using a JWT token with the type logout+jwt, and I'm getting the following exception:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__________Mono.error ⇢ at org.springframework.security.config.web.server.OidcBackChannelLogoutReactiveAuthenticationManager.lambda$decode$2(OidcBackChannelLogoutReactiveAuthenticationManager.java:92)
    *__Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.security.config.web.server.OidcBackChannelLogoutReactiveAuthenticationManager.decode(OidcBackChannelLogoutReactiveAuthenticationManager.java:88)
    |_           Mono.map ⇢ at org.springframework.security.config.web.server.OidcBackChannelLogoutReactiveAuthenticationManager.authenticate(OidcBackChannelLogoutReactiveAuthenticationManager.java:80)
    |_           Mono.map ⇢ at org.springframework.security.config.web.server.OidcBackChannelLogoutReactiveAuthenticationManager.authenticate(OidcBackChannelLogoutReactiveAuthenticationManager.java:83)
    *________Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.security.config.web.server.OidcBackChannelLogoutWebFilter.filter(OidcBackChannelLogoutWebFilter.java:90)

Caused by: com.nimbusds.jose.proc.BadJOSEException: JOSE header typ (type) logout+jwt not allowed
    at com.nimbusds.jose.proc.DefaultJOSEObjectTypeVerifier.verify(DefaultJOSEObjectTypeVerifier.java:148)
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:378)
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:340)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.createClaimsSet(NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.java:292)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriReactiveJwtDecoderBuilder.lambda$processor$13(NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.java:449)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539)

I've seen a recent change to support logout+jwt type in spring security for servlet (see here), but there is no way to support more type for reactive application.
I don't see any issues on spring-security github, so I wonder if there is a workaround for reactive/webflux application.

I've seen a recent change to support logout+jwt type in spring security for servlet pls link it

Yes, I saw the fix for servlet here, but it seems a similar changed was not done for webflux.

Back-Channel Logout implementation on Spring clients with oauth2Login is still pretty incomplete. For instance, it does not support cookie-based protection against CSRF, which should be a major issue with your Gateway. This should be fixed with Spring Security 6.4.
